# Automatic instantiation of custom class occuring on import in Actionscript 3 Flash Pro

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

While dissecting some AS3 code I have been given in Flash Pro CS6, I notice that one of the classes is never declared or instantiated, yet it is accessed, and by the same name as it's import statement.  Example:

```
import records;  //package file records.as
//Import instantiates records and it is usable!

records.zip = "12345";
trace (records.Zip, " ", records.Name);  //this works

//I thought this was always necessary
var r : records = new records();
r.init_records();
```

I notice that this variable 'records' is heavily accessed in several other imported classes, so I wanted to know if this is good practice, or open to errors?  If you know of one, you can point me to a resource that describes this 'feature'.  I know that Flash would never let me declare the following if I wanted to keep the class named 'records' and access it as a variable 'records':

```
var records : records = new records();
```

It just seems odd to me and I want to ensure the code is robust as I develop it further.

Finally, it would appear that later in the system, the following code is intended to reset the 'records' variable:

```
import records; //package file records.as
var new_records : records = new records();
new_records.init_records();
```

Is importing records.as again going to reset this automatically instantiated variable?  Or will declaring and calling init_records() on a new instance (that is never referenced after this point, it goes back to referencing 'records') going to reset the default instantiation?

Comment: Can you please help me understand your question a little better.. Are you asking whether you should use a singleton class, a static class or a normal class?
Importing a class doesn't re-instantiate the class, it only allows the script/frame access to that class.

Comment: Apparently, with some more study, this is a method of creating and using global variables throughout the code.  You import the .as file (technically, it looks like you don't even have to use an import statement, just include it in your compile list) and just refer to the class content through the name of the class itself.  What I'm trying to figure out is whether (1) importing the class again runs the constructor and thus modifies all of the existing global variables and (2) whether creating the first real instance of the class has any effect on the global variable version of the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like somebody is using records class as a global object where store global variables. That class should be a singleton so there is only one instance of it along the project but as you have found later on the system a place where it is getting instantiated that is a fail at the design pattern.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.  The global part I eventually figured out, but the instantiation into a variable that is never used strikes me as odd.  I am guessing that importing a class as a static global object a second time probably runs the constructor again and (in the case of this code) resets all the variables to default.  But I'll have to test it first.